# %2F not accepted in URL by apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have got this problem where I cannot enter %2F and %5C in the search box of my site because apache actively refuses to accept them in the url. I searched for my problem and found that I need to allow this behavior and so I did, adding this to my htaccess file:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

That did not solve the issue and I'm still getting "Object not found".

I have a url `/search/query%20goes%20here` and if I type any kind of slash in the query string like for example `/search/test%2F1` it will give me default apache 404 error. How do I fix it so it doesn't and gets to my rewrite rules?

## EDIT 1

I just noticed that this directive has caused internal server error on all of my pages and I cannot figure out why. It says in the apache manual that it is a part of the core module so I guess it cannot be a disabled module problem.

## EDIT 2

I tried moving the directive in the `httpd.conf` file just to see if it would work, but it still didn't. The 500 error disappeared though, but modifying that file is not satisfactory for my purpose, I would rather like to have a solution with an htaccess file.

Comment: _“I just noticed that this directive has caused internal server error on all of my pages and I cannot figure out why”_ – because, [as the manual clearly states](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes), the context for this directive is _server config, virtual host_ – which simply means it can not be used in .htaccess. // How are you handling those search URLs, any kind of rewriting or whatever?

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I actually stole my rewrite rules from laravel. I must be the biggest idiot on this planet and more, honestly. I spent, don't want to say how many, hours researching this problem, just "because", and what it turned out to be, just speechless.

Comment: _“and what it turned out to be, just speechless”_ – meaning, you found the problem? If so, please tell. Otherwise, show us your rewriting.

Comment: @CBroe I did not find it, you did. "_the context for this directive is server config, virtual host_" which also made me think why it didn't work when I tried adding it to `httpd.conf` but my brain is too tired to deal with this now. I added it to `httpd-vhosts.conf` to the respective virtual host and it is OK now. You should probably add this as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just noticed that this directive has caused internal server error on all of my pages and I cannot figure out why

As the http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes says, the [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) for this directive is *server config, virtual host* – which means it can not be used in `.htaccess`.

(Maybe you forgot to restart your server after adding it to the `httpd.conf`.)

Comment: No, I restarted it. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the URL generated on the client side to include a "?" to separate the query string from the server path.  Then in your server side code access the query string using generic "REQUEST" variables.  Most modern programming languages will automatically parse out the query string from the URL and present you a list of named variables to work with.

Comment: I don't want to. Even though this may even be the correct way I've spent waay too much time dealing with this crap to give up now, I need to find what the problem is.